# Update SQL database in rows where variable is not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to create a simple SQL `UPDATE` query which can check via an `IF` statement that the passed POST variable is empty or not. If empty then won't modify the original value, if not then update. I just can't figure out how I did it before.

It should be something like that, but not working:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Clients SET Name = IF(" . $_POST['edit_client_name'] .
    " = '', Name, " .
    mysqli_real_escape_string( $this -> link,  $_POST['edit_client_name'] ) .
    " WHERE Id=" . $_GET['selected_client'] . "";
```

Comment: Don't do that check in the database.  Check for valid input data in the application.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in your SQL query?  If the database shouldn't be updated then don't even invoke a SQL query at all.  It's kind of a waste of resources to connect to a database just to tell it not to update itself.

Comment: I want to do it with multiple rows, so if the user won't fill one of the inputs that that won't be overwritten.

Comment: @Isty001: It's probably still going to be a lot easier to just dynamically build the query instead of performing this check in the query itself.  Also, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks which can lead to lots of other problems.  You really shouldn't be executing user input as code in your database.

Comment: I always use escaping which should prevent it, now I'm just testing what is the shortest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this in application not query. Like

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_client_name'])){

  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this -> link,  $_POST['edit_client_name'] );
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this -> link, $_GET['selected_client'] );
  mysqli_query("UPDATE Clients SET Name = '".$name."' WHERE Id=".$id."');

}
```

Comment: But the point would be that I want to do it with multipel rows/variables. Should I check and query them one by one?

Comment: @Isty001: there is only one value of `$_POST['edit_client_name']` - you can perform an `UPDATE` to write multiple rows if that is set, if you wish.

Comment: no problem you can do it like this: if($_POST) {} now you can assign all post variable to each php variable than used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak through the SQL instead of doing checks in the DB.

I skipped the SQL Injection prevention part.

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['edited_client_name'])){
    $namequery = '';
}
else{
    $namequery = "Name = '".$_POST['edited_client_name']."'";
}

$sql = "UPDATE Clients SET ".$namequery." WHERE ID = ".$_GET['selected_client'];

echo $sql;
?>
```

returns:

```
UPDATE Clients SET Name = 'foo' WHERE ID = 1
```

when edited_client_name is provided,

else returns:

```
UPDATE Clients SET WHERE ID = 1
```

Hope this will give you an idea what to do with your code.